# Strange behaviour of 2 divs after relogging with another account

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I've been working on this, and got confronted with a serious issue. When I clean all the cache and session and cookies and when I just continue to work.

```
//to explain in plain text

<div id="player_information">...here goes content...</div>
<div id="contacts">....here goes content</div>
```

This is what I have written and it stands the first time I login without cache/coockies cleaned.

If I logout and I decide to loging with some other account, it happens this:

```
<div id="player_information">...here goes content...
     <div id="contacts">....here goes content</div>
</div>
```

Any tip?

`id="contacts"` by default is set to `display:none` and `id="player_information"` is set `display:block`. I have a navigation bar with a jQuery code making the work. When I click on `id="main"`, the  `id="contacts"` goes to `display:none"` and `id="player_information"` fades in, when I click `id="contact"` the  `id="contacts"` fades in and `id="player_information"` goes to `display:none"`.

Hope I was clear. Thank you :)

PS: I see the same result on chrome and firefox.

Images:[image]
[image]

EDIT: In response to @David Hoerster

```
$("#main").click(function(){
        $("#player_information").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#contacts").css({"display":"none"});
    });
    $("#contact").click(function(){
        $("#contacts").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#player_information").css({"display":"none"});
    });
```

EDIT2: In response to @David Hoerster

```
<div id="nav_bar">
            <ul>
                <li><div style="display: inline" id="main">Main</div></li>
                <li><div style="display: inline" id="contact">Contact</div></li>
                <li><a href='general/logout.php'>Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript/jquery involved?  If so, what's that look like?

Comment: Sounds like a missing closing div to me

Comment: What's `#main` referring to in your JavaScript?  I didn't see an element with an `id` of `main` in the screen shot you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this comes from CSS, your HTML may not be valid.

For example if you write this in HTML

```
<p>
  Content goes here
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
  </ul>
  Content here too
</p>
```

You browser will render it this way

```
<p>
  Content goes here
</p>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem</li>
</ul>
Content here too
<p></p>
```

Try to take a look this way.

Comment: But why does it render how it should at the first time and does not at the second time ?

Comment: maybe because your html structure is different when you are logged in and when you are not... if i were you i would definitely look this way.